# How to configure Apache Hadoop on windows systems

Tags: java, apache, hadoop

I have tried to configure Apache Hadoop on my Windows XP using cygwin. I have followed different tutorials from many sites, but cant succeeded. Can anyone explain the steps to configure Apache Hadoop on windows.